# How To Show Notification Text With HTML?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way for display IOS push notification text in HTML format?

Comment: Your question shows very little effort and research on your part.

Answer (score 5):

No rich text is not support by Apple Push Notification. You could have easily found this in the [APNS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)